# How to use the getAllowedHostsLimit API in Storages?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, network-storage

I'm trying to get allowed host limit for each volume using the API at http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage

I always get "0" for the allowed host limit value.
How can I get the right value?

Comment: See this forum:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314450/how-can-i-get-allowedhostslimit-for-each-volume-using-softlayer-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the following Restful and it returns the proper values

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/$StorageID/getAllowedHostsLimit

replace StorageId with the id of the object storage you want to get the allowed host limit
I just called this method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getAllowedHostsLimit

Make sure you have enough permissions to see the storages.