# How can I get allowedHostsLimit for each volume using SoftLayer API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to get allowed host limit for each volume. using the api in http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage

I always get "0" for the allowed host limit value.

How can I get the right value?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following Restful and it returns the proper values

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/$StorageID/getAllowedHostsLimit

replace StorageId with the id of the object storage you want to get the allowed host limit
```

I just called this method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getAllowedHostsLimit

Make sure you have enough permissions to see the storages

Regards